# Java - Cannot find symbol in default package

Tags: java, eclipse

Classes in tests package cannot find classes in default package.

If I move to classes in default package to tests, the errors disappear.

I'd like to know the reason of these errors.

[image: test case in tests package cannot resolve a class]

[image: a class in default package]

Comment: This is going to be entirely to do with how your Eclipse project's classpath is configured...

Comment: You should not use the default package at all. It is only a source of errors and compilation problems.

Comment: Please put the mouse on the error text and click f2, than paste the error message here. So that we can be aware of the what is the reason of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the class is situated in the different package and should be available to the current class via `import` directive. And because the class you want to import is in the default package that has not name, you can't do that, rather than move to the *named* package and apply the above.

Answer (score 3):

To have access to classes from another package, you should import this package.
But [according to JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) **you can't do it with default unnamed package**.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have a dependency on that module in which the AddChild1_wy_v1,java is located
- If it's a library then check if it is imported to your project and can be used
- Import the class to the class from which you are trying to use it
- ???
- Profit

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea to put classes in the default package.  Create a new explicitly named package for you classes and move them all there.  If you use Eclipse's Refactor->Move menu option, it will put in all the tedious package declarations for your classes.

Then your tests can import the package.